# android spareparts app source code

Tags: android, battery

I would like to understand how the battery parameters are used to display battery related information in the spareparts app in android 2.2 (FROYO). Can anyone please point me to this source code ?
More specifically I am interested in how spareparts->Battery Information is implemented.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a copy of the entire AOSP tree [here](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and following the instructions.

If you don't want to download the entire source tree, you can just get the git repository for spare parts.  Or you could also just read it online with a service that has posted the source code, such as [this one](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-development/com/android/spare_parts/SpareParts.java.htm).